# How can I arrange two sizes of images in a square grid?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to the following working with a non-table css aproach:

[image: design]

One of the problem I have to solve, is that the images can be different size, up to 512x512, but the whole element should keep 1:1 aspect ratio.

I tried making all images floating left, and set

```
.image {
  width: 33%;
  height: 33%;
}
```

Except for the first one which I set to `width: 66%; height: 66%`.

I also tried wrapping them in `div`s to make positioning easier:

```
<div class="all-the-images">
  <div class="image-row1">
    <div class="image-big">
      <div class="image"><img src="http://placehold.it/498x512" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-right">
      <div class="image"><img src="http://placehold.it/313x313" /></div>
      <div class="image"><img src="http://placehold.it/498x512" /></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-bottom">
    <div class="image"><img src="http://placehold.it/512x234" /></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="http://placehold.it/234x234" /></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="http://placehold.it/234x512" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/luckydonald/pen/dOwNGX (using less)
https://jsfiddle.net/luckydonald/96hqds80/ (generated css)

But there the different image sizes will destroy the rows.

Comment: Using percentage only scale the image to its original size. You need to set width and height attributes on `img` tag to scale the image to 1:1 proportion.

Comment: Isn't that possible with `max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%`?

Comment: Basically with those two properties set, you are saying the image can only be as big as it originally is. Percentage is only relative to its original size.

Comment: I know the served images are maximum 512x512. Does that help somehow?

Comment: Sigh. Percentage is **relative** to the size of the image. So if you have a image of 200*400, by setting `width: 50%; height: 50%`, you are getting a 100*200 image, to get a 1:1 image, you need to set `width: 100%; height: 50%`. So your best bet is to do this via javascript. Get the size of images as they load, and adjust their size to be 1:1.

Comment: What do you want to happen to an image that isn't 1:1? Do you want it to stretch? Or do you want it to have `width: 100%` and have it sit vertically in the middle of it's cell?

Comment: One solution you could use for the images of different sizes would be to have the image be a background image of the div and using `background-size: cover;` to fill the image with the box.

Comment: @TrevorNestman it should be center if it is smaller. I currently do that server side though.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a flexbox solution. IE11+ only, unless you use a [shim](https://github.com/jonathantneal/flexibility).

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0 auto;
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
}
.flex-container.vert {
  flex-direction: column;
}
.flex-container.outer {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vw;
}
.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  flex: 1;
}
.flex-item:nth-child(2n) {
  background: pink;
}
.flex-item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.double {
  flex: 2;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container outer vert">
  <div class="flex-container double">
    <div class="flex-item double">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/800/nature/1" />
    </div>

    <div class="flex-container vert">
      <div class="flex-item">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/800/nature/2" />
      </div>
      <div class="flex-item">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/800/nature/3" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/800/nature/4" />
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/800/nature/5" />
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/800/nature/6" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't thoroughly tested or polished, but what about using the CSS display properties of `table`, `table-row` and `table-cell`?

```css
span {
 border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:200px; height: 200px; display: table;">
<div display="table-row">
 <span style="width: 66%; height: 66%; display: table-cell">
  <img style="width: 100%" src="http://placehold.it/498x512" />
 </span>
 <span style="width: 33%; display: table-cell; vertical-align: top;">
  <img style="width: 100%;" src="http://placehold.it/512x512" />
  <img style="width: 100%;" src="http://placehold.it/512x512" />
 </span>
</div>
<div display="table-row">
 <span style="width: 33%; display: table-cell; vertical-align: top;">
  <img style="width: 100%;" src="http://placehold.it/512x512" />
 </span>
 <span style="width: 33%; display: table-cell; vertical-align: top;">
  <img style="width: 100%;" src="http://placehold.it/512x512" />
 </span>
 <span style="width: 33%; display: table-cell; vertical-align: top;">
  <img style="width: 100%;" src="http://placehold.it/512x512" />
 </span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/luckydonald/yp8cb6hk/1/ This still has the problem of the 6th element behaving strange, when using differently sized images.

Answer (score 1):

Well... not sure if you're coming back to this question anytime soon. This is what I did using floats (like you had talked about). I have images that aren't proportionate set to `width: 100%` and `height: auto`. Again, I'm not sure what you want to happen for images that aren't perfect squares (1:1 proportions).

```css
.allimages {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vw;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #f3f3f3;
}
.image-container {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 33.333%;
  width: 33.333%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #222;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.image-container.big {
  height: 66.655%;
  width: 66.655%;
}
.image-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="allimages">
  <div class="image-container big">
    <image src="http://lorempixel.com/700/700/cats"/>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <image src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/sports"/>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <image src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/food"/>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <image src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/sports"/>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <image src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/food"/>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <image src="http://lorempixel.com/500/700/sports"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I currently am making sure they are square images on server side.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't like table css, you could do this too:

```
<div class="all-the-images">
  <div class="image-row1">
    <div class="image-big">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/498x512" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-right">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/313x313" />
      <img src="http://placehold.it/498x512" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-row2">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/512x234" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/234x234" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/234x512" />
  </div>
</div>

.all-the-images {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: green;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.all-the-images .image-row1 {
  height: 66.66666667%;
}
.all-the-images .image-row1 .image-big {
  width: 66.66666667%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.all-the-images .image-row1 .image-right {
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.all-the-images .image-row2 {
  height: 33.33333333%;
}
.all-the-images .image-row2 img {
  max-width: 33.33333333%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/arleonard54/yu3Ls4zL/